# Is there an idiomatic way to update just certain fields in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Is there any good way of having an `UPDATE` request with optional data?
what I have now is:

- An example `Author`

```json
{
    "id": "203ede72-45af-4029-8055-e1c43656d42d",
    "first_name": "Willdon",
    "last_name": "Surgey"
},
```

- The postgres function to update the author

```sql
-- UPDATE
create or replace
function update_author(target_id uuid, i_first_name varchar(50), i_last_name varchar(50))
returns json
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare inserted_author authors%rowtype;
begin
     update authors a
     set first_name = i_first_name,
          last_name = i_last_name
     where a.id = target_id
     returning * into inserted_author;

return row_to_json(inserted_author);
end;
$$;
```

Now, if I do a `PUT` request at `/author/203ede72-45af-4029-8055-e1c43656d42d` with body

```json
{
    "last_name": "Smith"
}
```

It becomes

```json
{
    "id": "203ede72-45af-4029-8055-e1c43656d42d",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "Smith"
}
```

I want it to keep `first_name` if only `last_name` is supplied

Comment: `first_name = coalesce(i_first_name, first_name)` is one way but I suspect that, like Oracle, it will add to the write ahead log the fact that `first_name` will be assigned its current value when `i_first_name is null`, which is waste. Depending upon your *perfection* tendencies to avoid this waste, you would execute one of two different update statements depending upon `i_first_name`.

Comment: unfortunately it assumes `i_first_name` as an empty string and assigns the empty string

Comment: Use `case` then. Since there's a distinction between null and empty string, you can enumerate what you want to do for both.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was that I initally queried the full `author` object from the database, and then used `golang`'s `Unmarshal` to selectively change properties, and then passed the full data into the postgres function.

NOTE: If you are using this workaround, be sure to have some sort of validation, so that your user(s) can't break your database with a query like
`PUT /author/f3ef41a5-fe1e-4180-92bf-8b87e879211d`

```
{
    "id": "g3ef41a5-fe1e-4180-92bf-8b87e879211d",
    "last_name": "Smith"
}
```

notice that the first letter of the UUID has been changed, this could break stuff.